# connecting to a local mongoDB and making transaction in c++11

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11

I have some experience with mysql Database transactions using .Net but I was trying to connect to my local mongoDB and interacting with it using c++ 11 (making transactions like insert, delete, update the DB contents). It does not seem to be obvious like in .Net where you would simply make a connection to DB and then interacting with your database (connection string + transactions). I would like to have a simple working snippet that I could use and build up on it.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/)?

Comment: Thank you but I'm having some issues with the compilation line (linking the mongoDB components to my program seem to be a pain).

Comment: There's not really enough detail given to help you with that.